# Adding file with specific content from secretsmanager into machine on startup using AWS CloudFormation

Tags: authentication, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation to provision a Linux Instance. During startup I want to add a file into a specific folder which content comes from a secretstring which resides in the secrets manager.
I tried to add the file using UserData and MetaData, however, instead of what it should do, namely, adding the correct content from the secrets manager to the file, it just adds the string as is which depicts the location of the content instead of the content itself. This is my code:

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    config:
      files:
        /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys:
          content: !Sub |
            '{{ resolve:secretsmanager:
          arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:account:secret:secretname:
            SecretString:
              secretstringpath }}'
          mode: "000644"
          owner: "ansible"
          group: "ansible"
Properties:
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      yum update -y
      groupadd -g 110 ansible
      adduser ansible -g ansible
      mkdir /home/ansible/.ssh
      yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v \
        --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
        --resource LinuxEC2Instance \
        --region ${AWS::Region}
      cat /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

What the cat command prints is this here:

> {{ resolve:secretsmanager:
> arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:account:secret:secretname:
> SecretString:
> secretstringpath }}

instead of the the pathname of the file.
How do I ensure that it adds the content of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have dynamic references to secretsmanager within Cloudformation::Init

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as switching your quotation marks from single to double:

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    config:
      files:
        /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys:
          content: !Sub |
            "{{ resolve:secretsmanager:
          arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:account:secret:secretname:
            SecretString:
              secretstringpath }}"
          mode: "000644"
          owner: "ansible"
          group: "ansible"
```